# Can't authenticate user with postgresql on Linux Centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos

PG 9.4
Centos 6.7

I successfully installed Postgres 9.4 on Centos. I am checking my authentication through pgAdmin. I can create new users etc with the Centos terminal.

However, after the user and passwords are created, I can't use them to access localhost on Postgres. I get the error: 'FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "pguser"'

The weird thing is, I can login using my linux username and NO password. However, as soon as I create a new username and password, it doesn't work.

/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf file as in [password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038342/password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres):

```
# Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
local   all         postgres                          ident
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

How do I set up a new superuser and password that will properly authenticate? (This user is going to be used to read/write to pg in a ruby on rails app)

Edit: the answer provided below works. You may have to restart your computer or find a good way to kill/restart pg, looks like sometimes the changes to the pg_hba.conf file don't take.

Comment: Its the method you are using to connect to the database.. You need to set it to password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your pg_hba.conf file to accept password as the METHOD to get in. If I am reading this correctly, you are attempting to log in to postgres locally with a user and password you configured. So you should configure pg_hba.conf as such:

```
# Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
local   all         postgres                          ident
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     password
```

After this is done, you should be able to log in locally with the username and password.

Comment: I commented out what I had in the pg_hba.conf file and inserted the lines you recommended. Created a new user in the terminal, and still getting the same error :(

Comment: Hmm ok, let me take a look at their documentation and figure out what to do. Its been a while since i used postgres :)

Comment: With the proposed settings my Linux username doesn't work either to access localhost

Comment: thank you. Yeah, it's probably something with this file, I can't seem to figure it out though. All this worked perfectly on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try restarting postgres once the change is made? There are only two types of password authentication: md5 and password. Md5 uses MD5 encrypted passwords whereas password uses cleartext.. Cleartext should work in this case...

Comment: Also, do not comment everything out. Just change local's METHOD from md5 to password

Comment: Hmm.. yeah I've been restarting postgres and even opening a new terminal window just in case. I'll try changing the local method.

Comment: If your trying to access Postgres db locally, you should have changed the local method to password..

Comment: Still doesn't run even with the local method as password. I create the user with: "createuser -s pguser" then set a password with "\password pguser" - that sound alright?

Comment: OK wow.. your answer is correct.. my issue was closing the terminal windows and restarting pgadmin turned out to not be enough - had to fully reboot for the pg_hba.conf to take. thank you for the help

Comment: Sure, if you can checkmark this answer that would be great :)